Error while data passing from .NET code in form of object to SQL Server user-defined table type
I need to upload and update file bytes from C# to SQL Server, but I am getting this error in C#:

Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Implicit conversion from data type nvarchar(max) to varbinary(max) is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.'

C# code:
public async Task<dynamic> UpdateBulkData(IList<EodUpdateDto> eods)
{
    string strTrace = MethodLogger.GetExecutionInfo(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod());
    logger.LogDebug($"Executing {strTrace} with parameter : {JsonSerializer.Serialize(eods)}");
 
    string sqlQuery = $"{StoredProcedures.UPDATE_BULK_EOD} @EODS";
    var paramEods = new SqlParameter() { ParameterName = "@EODS", Value = eods.ToDataTable(), SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured, TypeName = "EODType" };
    await sqlExecutor.ExecuteSqlRawAsync(sqlQuery, [paramEods]);

    return true;
}

Code Definition of ToDataTable
public static DataTable ToDataTable<T>(this IList<T> items)
{
     DataTable dataTable = new(typeof(T).Name);
 
     //Get all the properties
     PropertyInfo[] Props = typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
     foreach (PropertyInfo prop in Props)
     {
         //Defining type of data column gives proper data table 
         dynamic? type = (prop.PropertyType.IsGenericType && prop.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>) ? Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(prop.PropertyType) : prop.PropertyType);
         //Setting column names as Property names
         dataTable.Columns.Add(prop.Name, type);
     }
     if (items != null && items.Count > 0)
     {
         foreach (T item in items)
         {
             dynamic values = new object[Props.Length];
             for (int i = 0; i < Props.Length; i++)
             {
                 //inserting property values to datatable rows
                 values[i] = Props[i].GetValue(item, null);
             }
             dataTable.Rows.Add(values);
         }
     }
     //put a breakpoint here and check datatable
     return dataTable;
}

Here value of StoredProcedures.UPDATE_BULK_EOD is usp_UpdateEODData_U.
This is the definition of EodUpdateDto model class:
public class EodUpdateDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ActionBy { get; set; } = default!;
    public bool Accepted { get; set; }
    public bool VerifySelfPay { get; set; }
    public string Claim { get; set; } = default!;
    public bool OnHold { get; set; }
    public string HoldReason { get; set; } = default!;
    public string AttachFileName { get; set; } = default!;
    public string AttachFileType { get; set; } = default!;
    public byte[]? AttachFileContent { get; set; } = default!;
}

Here is the design of the SQL Server user-defined table type:
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[EODType] AS TABLE
(
    [ID] [int] NULL,
    [ActionBy] [varchar](200) NOT NULL,
    [Accepted] [bit] NULL,
    [VerifySelfPay] [bit] NULL,
    [Claim] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [OnHold] [bit] NULL,
    [HoldReason] [varchar](200) NULL,
    [AttachFileName] [varchar](300) NULL,
    [AttachFileContent] [varbinary](max) NULL,
    [AttachFileType] [varchar](50) NULL
)

This is the stored procedure to which the data is passed:
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_UpdateEODData_U]
    @EODS [dbo].[EODType] READONLY
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
 
    UPDATE EOD 
    SET 
        Accepted = E2.Accepted, 
        VerifySelfPay = E2.VerifySelfPay, 
        Claim = E2.Claim, 
        OnHold = E2.OnHold, 
        HoldReason = E2.HoldReason,
        HoldDate = IIF(E2.HoldReason IS NOT NULL, dbo.GetDateEST(), null),
        AttachFileName = E2.AttachFileName,
        AttachFileContent = E2.AttachFileContent,
        AttachFileType = E2.AttachFileType,
        ActionBy = E2.ActionBy
    FROM EOD E1
    INNER JOIN @EODS E2 ON E1.ID = E2.ID;
END


The error is telling you the problem here. In your C# your variable AttachFileContent is defined as a string?, which as a SQL Server data type is nvarchar, not varbinary.

If you'll forgive my partially off-topic concern, but I have a personal crusade against = default!; <-- Despite the fact this appears in Microsoft's own documentation (for EF, not C#, FWIW), I contend there is never any legitimate reason to use this. Nullable warnings are better suppresed with a #pragma, whereas using null! or default! does more harm than good, and it doesn't do any good either.

You don't show the code for the most important bit eods.ToDataTable()

@DaleK: I updated the code for ToDataTable

You just need to debug that process and work out why it's adding a string parameter instead of a varbinary/byte[]

You C# type for AttachFileContent should be byte[] because the database column is varbinary.
But you should reconsider saving binary file content to your database. Your table/db size will balloon, backups and restores will take ages, and it will only continue to grow.
Instead, you should be saving the content somewhere like S3 or on a file system and then retain a link to the location in the database.
Or even better, save the content to a file system with a common naming scheme like the id and then you won't need to save the location, it will be the same for all with the id inserted. If you need to retain the file name and type you can always save that in the database and then use that to send the data back out.

sorry, I posted the old code now updated the code with byte[] for AttachFileContent in c#, it's legacy system so as per client requirement we are going with same file store in db.

Just by changing order of property "AttachFileContent" from down to up in EodUpdateDto model class of C# resolved the issue.
public class EodUpdateDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ActionBy { get; set; } = default!;
    public bool Accepted { get; set; }
    public bool VerifySelfPay { get; set; }
    public string Claim { get; set; } = default!;
    public bool OnHold { get; set; }
    public string HoldReason { get; set; } = default!;
    public string AttachFileName { get; set; } = default!;
    public byte[]? AttachFileContent { get; set; } = default!;
    public string AttachFileType { get; set; } = default!;
    
}

